# Array of objects with nested relations in Laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, orm

How can I return a nested structure from 3 Models with one-to-many nested relations?

Example:

Models `State, Region, Province`

Every `State` can have many `Regions` and every `Region` can have many `Provinces`.

My relations work perfectly, but I don't know if there is a way to make one JsonArray containing every `State`, and for every `State` every `Region` and so on going down in relations.

I hope to be clear, if you need I can post my code.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you can do something like: `State::with('regions.provinces')->get()->toArray();`.

Comment: That would probably work but he states in question he actually wants json so probably doing `State::with('regions.provinces')->get()->toJson();` is a bit better.